# Why `CenterDot[var_] := var` with `Flat` attribute induces infinite recursion?

Tags: pattern-matching, recursion

I am trying to define some rules for `CenterDot`. One thing I don't understand is that if I define

```
SetAttributes[CenterDot, Flat]
CenterDot[var_] := var
```

`CenterDot[x]` will induce infinite recursion. I have tried to use `Trace`, but could not find why there was a recursion. I am expecting `CenterDot[x]` being evaluated to `x`.

Comment: It seems to depend on the order of definitions, compare these two: `f1[x_] := x; SetAttributes[f1, Flat]` and `SetAttributes[f2, Flat]; f2[x_] := x`. Only `f2` is affected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is age-old behavior (likely back to ~Mathematica 1.0). Perhaps at that time in the 1990s it would be solidly considered a bug, but by 2020 it's been the behavior for so long that I think it's unlikely to be changed.

I have two suggestions for working around the behavior:

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
Verbatim[f][x_] := x

In[4]:= f[1]

Out[4]= 1

In[5]:= ClearAll[f2]
SetAttributes[f2, {OneIdentity, Flat}];
f2[x_] := x

In[8]:= f2[1]

Out[8]= 1
```

Comment: I wonder why it never got fixed. Anybody relying on this behavior?

Comment: I think in 2020 that’s a factor. Maybe not explicitly relying on this behavior, but worrying about any unintended downstream effects from the change.